# Overlaying a PDF page with a grid with (0,0) at the bottom left and (10,10) at the top right

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put (0,0) at the bottom left and (10,10) at the top right corner of the PDF page.  Vertical and horizontal scales are not necessarily the same.

An unexpected output is given as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\includepdf[pagecommand={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \begin{scope}[x={(current page.south east)},y={(current page.north west)}]
     \draw[help lines,xstep=0.1,ystep=0.1,red] (0,0) grid (1,1);
     \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10} {\node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {\x}; }
     \foreach \y in {0,1,...,10} {\node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {\y}; }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}},pages=1,fitpaper=true]{example-image-a.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you assume that the tikz picture is placed at the bottom left, but it isn't. pagecommands puts it into the center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\AddToHookNext{shipout/foreground}
{
  \put(0,-\pdfpageheight)
   {%
     \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \begin{scope}[x={(current page.south east)},y={(current page.north west)}]
       \draw[help lines,xstep=0.1,ystep=0.1,red] (0,0) grid (1,1);
       \node at (0.5,0.5){xxxxx};
       \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10} {\node [anchor=south] at (\x/10,0) {\x}; }
       \foreach \y in {0,1,...,10} {\node [anchor=west] at (0,\y/10) {\y}; }
     \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
   }
   
}
\includepdf[pages=1,fitpaper=true]{example-image-a.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]